# What does "against which it must be seen" mean?

Tags: prepositions

A sentence from TOEFL reading: " The best signal depends not only on its brightness but also on how well it contrasts with the background against which it must be seen."

My question is, I can not understand the rear part of the sentence:"it contrasts with the background against which it must be seen." 
Specifically, what confuse me is "against which" and model verb " must". 
Please help me out. Thankyou!

Comment: It sounds like a comparison. E.g., 'Your suggestions should be viewed against similar suggestions made by others as of now."

Comment: Some background noise (metaphorical usage) is inevitable. No matter how bright a signal is, if there is insufficient contrast with the background, it will not 'stand out' clearly. eg taking a photograph of a firework display with the sun behind it.

Answer (score 2):

A signal is seen against a background. For instance, an aircraft's [navigation lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_light#Aviation_navigation_lights) are seen against the background of the sky. And this background is "the background against which the signal must be seen".

Comment: The OP's question is." Specifically, what confuse me is "against which" and model verb " must". Your answer doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Just add that the word *which* substitutes for the antecedent *background*.